# Network of senders and receivers in C++

Tags: c++, graph, observer-pattern

I am trying to create a Sender-Receiver Network. What do I mean under a Sender-Receiver Network. That means that there is some structure which consists of Nodes and connections between them which will be called Channels. Through this channels nodes can transfer some data. So one node can be a sender and another - a receiver. I would like to emphasize that there is no some restriction to be either a sender or a receiver for a node. Each of them (nodes) is able to send or receive data.

## Node

`Node` is a unit that can be send/receive data to/from another node.

## Channel

`Channel` is a unit that transfers data from one node to another. More precisely, a channel connects two nodes with some feature which in this case is a weight. Weight is just a number which says how strongly two nodes are connected i.e. what is the contribution of sent data from \$j\$th node in the received data of \$i\$th node. This could be expressed in the following equation:

$$d^{(i)}_{received} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}w_{ij}d^{(j)}_{sent}$$

## My realization of SRN

I find the Observer Design Pattern pretty attractive so I used it:

```
//Connector.h
//This class is base for Channel class.
#ifndef CONNECTOR_H
#define CONNECTOR_H

class Connector
{                                                                          
    public :
    virtual double ActivateChannel() = 0;
};   
#endif
```

This is the implementation of the `Node`:

```
//Node.h
#ifndef NODE_H                                                             
#define NODE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "Connector.h"

class Node
{
    protected : 
        double initialData;
        std::vector<Connector*> senders;  
        std::vector<Connector*> receivers;

    public : 
        Node( double initialData=0 ) : initialData( initialData ) { };
        ~Node() { };

        void RegisterSender( Connector* sender );
        void RegisterReceiver( Connector* receiver );

        double ReceiveDataFromSenders(); 
};


void Node::RegisterSender( Connector* sender ) 
{
    senders.push_back( sender );
}


void Node::RegisterReceiver( Connector* receiver ) 
{
    receivers.push_back( receiver );
}


double Node::ReceiveDataFromSenders()
{
    double receivedData = 0.;
    for( auto &sender : senders )
    {
        receivedData += sender->ActivateChannel();
    }
    return receivedData + initialData;
}
#endif
```

This is the implementation of the `Channel`:

```
//Channel.h
#ifndef CHANNEL_H                                                     
#define CHANNEL_H

#include "Connector.h"
#include "Node.h"

class Node;

class Channel : public Connector
{        
    protected :
        Node* sender;
        Node* receiver;
        double weight;

    public :
        Channel( Node* sender, Node* receiver, double weight );
        ~Channel() { };

        double ActivateChannel(); 
};       

Channel::Channel( Node* sender, Node* receiver, double weight )
{        
    this->sender   = sender;
    this->receiver = receiver;
    this->weight   = weight;

    //SENDER registrates this connection in its RECEIVER list
    //RECEIVER registrates this connection in its SENDER list
    (this->sender)->RegisterReceiver( this );
    (this->receiver)->RegisterSender( this );
}        


double Channel::ActivateChannel()
{        
    return sender->ReceiveDataFromSenders() * weight;
}     
#endif
```

Here is how to use this:

```
//main.cpp
#include "Channel.h"                                              
#include <iostream> 

int main()
{
    Node n1(1), n2(1), n3, n4, n5;
    //create connections between nodes
    //Channel( sender, receiver, weight )
    Channel d1( &n1, &n3, 1);
    Channel d2( &n1, &n4, 1);
    Channel d3( &n2, &n3, 1);
    Channel d4( &n2, &n4, 1);
    Channel d5( &n3, &n5, 2);
    Channel d6( &n4, &n5, 2);

    std::cout << n5.ReceiveDataFromSenders() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
8
```

Comment: _"Please, do not take into account possible absence of something important in general (such as existence of some obvious exceptions) in my code which likely were skipped intentionally."_ Disclaimers like this give you an easy rebuttal to many issues, and are unfair to reviewers, who have to guess at your intentions. Please either post your real code, or remove the disclaimer.